# Fixing values in columns of a csv file with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am trying to find a way to programmatically search for values in a specific column within a csv file and replace the values if the conditions are met.

Essentially, I will be dealing with a lot of large files with inconsistent data for the State value (Some use NY, others use New York). I need to try to replace most, if not all, with the ISO standard (e.g. NY) for all states.

How would I go about changing this:

```
data1,data2,New York,data4
data1,data2,NY,data4
data1,data2,Ohio,data4
```

To this:

```
data1,data2,NY,data4
data1,data2,NY,data4
data1,data2,OH,data4
```

All without creating a new file.

Comment: 1. Create a mapping (a dictionary) between the verbose state name and the abbreviated one. 2. Instead of worrying about not creating a new file just create a new one and delete the old one using `os.remove`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the following to convert your column 3 entries:

```
import csv

short = {'New York':'NY', 'NY':'NY', 'Ohio':'OH'}
entries = []

with open('data.txt', 'rb') as f_input:
    for cols in csv.reader(f_input):
        cols[2] = short[cols[2]]
        entries.append(cols)

with open('data.txt', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv.writer(f_output).writerows(entries)
```

This would result in `data.txt` looking like:

```
data1,data2,NY,data4
data1,data2,NY,data4
data1,data2,OH,data4
```

This assumes that your file is small enough to fit into memory.